# listfragment exception:OnFragmentInteractionListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I am using `listfragment` and `activity` to call it, I implemented the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in the activity and defined it in the list fragment, but it still doesn't work, could someone help me?

Update: I noticed that in CrimeFragment the method onFragmentInteraction in interface OnFragmentInteractionListener is marked unused.

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by AaronC on 9/29/2015.
 */
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;
private static final String TAG="CrimeListFragment";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title);
    mCrimes=CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();

    ArrayAdapter<Crime> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Crime>(getActivity        (),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mCrimes);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Crime c=(Crime)(getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
    Log.d(TAG,c.getTitle()+" was clicked");
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}

package com.largerexer.aaronc.criminalintent;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

/**
 * Created by AaronC on 9/29/2015.
 */
public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity implements CrimeListFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected Fragment createFragment() {
    return new CrimeListFragment();
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
}
```

and this is the SingleFragmentActivity:

```
package com.largerexer.aaronc.criminalintent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

/**
 * Created by AaronC on 9/29/2015.
 */
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

protected abstract Fragment createFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if(fragment==null){
        fragment=new CrimeFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,fragment).commit();
    }
}
}
```

The log still shows:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.largerexer.aaronc.criminalintent/com.largerexer.aaronc.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.largerexer.aaronc.criminalintent.CrimeListActivity@e1467ac must
>   implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Activity and fragments Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems you have removed pre generated onAttachMethod .

Comment: Hi  subhash, there is no pregen onAttach, I am using android studio and it extends a ListFragment